# SQL query to get column of the next row to be of column of a row and the second row of the column to the next row by customer ordered date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a SQL query to get the column of the next row to be a column of a row. the test example is as follows

[image]

I want to get SQL query to get the result as follow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of SQL Server, you can use the [`LEAD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) window function, but prior to 2012, I believe the easiest way to achieve this is with outer applies:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Customer CHAR(1), [Date] DATE, Item VARCHAR(10));

INSERT @T VALUES
('A', '2016-01-01', 'Pen A'),
('A', '2016-01-05', 'Pen B'),
('A', '2016-01-06', 'Pen C'),
('A', '2016-01-07', 'Pen D'),
('B', '2016-01-01', 'Pen A'),
('B', '2016-01-05', 'Pen B'),
('B', '2016-01-06', 'Pen C'),
('B', '2016-01-07', 'Pen IS');

SELECT T.Customer,
       T.FirstOrderedDate,
       T.FirstOrderedItem,
       T.SecondOrderedDate,
       T.SecondOrderedItem,
       ThirdOrderedDate = T3.[Date],
       ThirdOrderedItem = T3.Item
FROM
(
    SELECT T1.Customer,
           FirstOrderedDate = T1.[Date],
           FirstOrderedItem = T1.Item,
           SecondOrderedDate = T2.[Date],
           SecondOrderedItem = T2.Item
    FROM @T AS T1
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 T2.Customer, T2.[Date], T2.Item
        FROM @T AS T2
        WHERE T2.Customer = T1.Customer
        AND T2.[Date] > T1.[Date]
        ORDER BY T2.[Date]
    ) AS T2
) AS T
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T3.Customer, T3.[Date], T3.Item
    FROM @T AS T3
    WHERE T3.Customer = T.Customer
    AND T3.[Date] > T.SecondOrderedDate
    ORDER BY T3.[Date]
) AS T3;
```

Note: Seeing as you haven't really given any specifics about a customer ordering different items on the same date, I've just assumed that each customer has ordered only one thing on a given date, but if that's not the case, then you'd have to adjust the query logic slightly.